# numpy - resize array filling with 0

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following numpy array:

```
a = np.array([[1.1,0.8,0.5,0,0],[1,0.85,0.5,0,0],[1,0.8,0.5,1,0]])
```

with `shape = (3,5)`.

I would like to reshape and resize it to a new array with `shape = (3,8)`, filling the new values in each row with `0`. So far I tried the following approach:

```
b = np.resize(a,(3,8))
```

But it returns:

```
[[ 1.1   0.8   0.5   0.    0.    1.    0.85  0.5 ]
 [ 0.    0.    1.    0.8   0.5   1.    0.    1.1 ]
 [ 0.8   0.5   0.    0.    1.    0.85  0.5   0.  ]]
```

instead of the expected (for me):

```
[[ 1.1   0.8   0.5   0.    0.    0.    0.    0. ]
 [ 1.    0.85  0.5   0.    0.    0.    0.    0. ]
 [ 1.    0.8   0.5   1.    0.    0.    0.    0. ]]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the doc of `np.resize()`:

> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new
>   array is filled with repeated copies of a.

Zeros are not used, but actual values of `a`.

Instead, you could use `np.hstack()` and `np.zeros()` :

```
np.hstack([a, np.zeros([3, 3])])
```

Edit: I have not tested the speed, so I suggest you have a look a other solutions too.

Answer (score 22):

Use [`np.lib.pad`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) -

```
np.lib.pad(a, ((0,0),(0,3)), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
```

Sample run -

```
In [156]: a
Out[156]: 
array([[ 1.1 ,  0.8 ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.85,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.8 ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.  ]])

In [157]: np.lib.pad(a, ((0,0),(0,3)), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
Out[157]: 
array([[ 1.1 ,  0.8 ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.85,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.8 ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```

---

Runtime tests -

This section covers runtime tests for the approaches posted thus far for the size listed in the question and scaling it up by `100x`. Here are the timing test results -

```
In [212]: def init_based(a,N):
     ...:   b = np.zeros((a.shape[0], a.shape[1]+N))
     ...:   b[:, :a.shape[1]] = a
     ...:   return b
     ...: 

In [213]: a = np.random.rand(3,5)

In [214]: N = 3

In [215]: %timeit np.lib.pad(a, ((0,0),(0,N)), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
     ...: %timeit np.hstack([a, np.zeros([a.shape[0], N])])
     ...: %timeit np.concatenate((a,np.zeros((a.shape[0],N))), axis=1)
     ...: %timeit init_based(a,N)
     ...: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 32.7 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 11.2 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.49 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 3: 5.67 µs per loop

In [216]: a = np.random.rand(300,500)

In [217]: N = 300

In [218]: %timeit np.lib.pad(a, ((0,0),(0,N)), 'constant', constant_values=(0))
     ...: %timeit np.hstack([a, np.zeros([a.shape[0], N])])
     ...: %timeit np.concatenate((a,np.zeros((a.shape[0],N))), axis=1)
     ...: %timeit init_based(a,N)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.99 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.71 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.72 ms per loop
```

Comment: Where are Divakar's typical speed comparison with other answers :) ? I wanna know

Comment: @M.Massias haha well soon I guess, once we get all in ;) I would think some solution with `np.concatenate` would be really fast!

Comment: @M.Massias Added them and as suspected `np.concatenate`  seems fastest, as other concatenation approaches are based upon them.

Comment: @HarshTrivedi: [`resize()` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47787117/4279) seems more natural and efficient.

Answer (score 8):

Definitely you can use [resize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.resize.html).

> If the new array is larger than the original array, then the new array is filled with repeated copies of a. **Note that this behavior is different from a.resize(new_shape) which fills with zeros instead of repeated copies of a.**

```
b = a.transpose().copy()
b.resize((8,3), refcheck=False)
b = a.transpose()
```

which outputs:

```
[[ 1.1   0.8   0.5   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 1.    0.85  0.5   0.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]
 [ 1.    0.8   0.5   1.    0.    0.    0.    0.  ]]
```

**Limitation:**

Filling with 0s can be only applied to the 1st dimension.

Answer (score 5):

Another option (although `np.hstack` is probably best [as in M. Massias' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33256879/1728179)).

Initialise an array of zeros:

```
b = np.zeros((3, 8))
```

Fill using slice syntax:

```
b[:3, :5] = a
```

Comment: perfect answer!

Answer (score 3):

np.concatenate

```
np.concatenate((a,np.zeros((3,3))), axis=1)
array([[ 1.1 ,  0.8 ,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.85,  0.5 ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 1.  ,  0.8 ,  0.5 ,  1.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])
```